# Add new site to Magento redirects

Tags: magento-1.5

I am trying to add a new site to Magento 1.5.1.0.

I have added the domain http://www.marisadirect.co.uk/ and set it to point to the correct location. I have also setup the new site in Magento admin and added it to the htaccess file.

```
SetEnvIf Host .*marisadirect.​co.​uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=marisam_en
SetEnvIf Host .*marisadirect.​co.​uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

However when I try to access the site through my browser I get a 302 Temporary redirect to the site admin page.

Have I missed something?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you clear your Magento cache? And did you also clear your browser cache? It's pretty common that your browser saves a URL to be redirected. When opening the page in a different browser or incognito mode, it might not happen. If that doesn't help either, you could debug it by checking if the error occurs in Magento or in the htaccess by adding a die or exit at the start of your index.php file.